# What are the internal implementation differences between PureComponent and Component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I was asked of the question: `What are the internal implementation differences between PureComponent and Component in React` in yesterday's job interview, and my lack of knowledge of this question screwed up my interview.

I know the detailed differences between them, including EVERYTHING in React's documentation, and when and how to use them, but I do not know their IMPLEMENTATION in React's SOURCE CODE.

Can you give me some brief summaries of this question, and some recommendations of how to walkthrough the React's source code the get a deeper knowledge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure components and normal components are virtually identical except for the fact that a normal component will not handle the life cycle method `shouldComponentUpdate()` for you. In a pure component, when props or state changes, the pure component will automatically check by doing a shallow comparison on both props and state to see if the component needs to re-render.

A regular component won't do this comparison (unless you specify some comparison in `shouldComponentUpdate()` yourself).

You can find a good write-up on the differences [here](https://lucybain.com/blog/2018/react-js-pure-component/). As well as the actual source code differences [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/a129259ad6a61790fe1912a87cb45018d942f90c/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberClassComponent.js#L273)

Here's the actual code difference.

```
if (ctor.prototype && ctor.prototype.isPureReactComponent) {
  return (
    !shallowEqual(oldProps, newProps) || !shallowEqual(oldState, newState)
  );
}
```

Comment: What are the differences of implementations between them in the source code level?

Comment: @cmal you can find the difference in the second link I added. But i'll append it to my answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is `PureComponent` has a `shouldComponentUpdate` pre-defined. You can see it in the current [react code on github](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/a129259ad6a61790fe1912a87cb45018d942f90c/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberClassComponent.js#L273):

```
if (ctor.prototype && ctor.prototype.isPureReactComponent) {
  return (
    !shallowEqual(oldProps, newProps) || !shallowEqual(oldState, newState)
  );
}
```

It simply checks props and state for shallow equality.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the existing answers, it's true that the `PureComponent` has a pre-defined behavior for `shouldComponentUpdate`, but this implementation difference appears during the reconciliation process.

If you were to compare the [`Component` and `PureComponent` classes](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js), you would see they have almost the same prototype (Except for the `isPureReactComponent` property), as defined in:

```
function ComponentDummy() {}
ComponentDummy.prototype = Component.prototype;
.
.
.
const pureComponentPrototype = (PureComponent.prototype = new ComponentDummy());
pureComponentPrototype.constructor = PureComponent;
// Avoid an extra prototype jump for these methods.
Object.assign(pureComponentPrototype, Component.prototype);
pureComponentPrototype.isPureReactComponent = true;
```